# Excel ISBLANK IF Formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

So far I have this but will not work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AJ17:AM17),"",IF(AD17=0,"", AD17))
```

What I want to happen is:

If Cells in a row AJ through AM are 0 or Blank then do not show Price from Column AD in Column AR(just leave it blank). 
If there are any numbers in row AJ through AM (AJ AK AL AM) then price in column AD shows up in column AR.

One last thing... If cell in a row in AD is blank AR is Blank but if there is text or a price in column AD that is what shows in Column AR. Thanks for your help!!!

My table I am having issues with:

[image: My table I am having issues with is here for you to view]

Comment: Please format your text to be readable and add the table content directly in the text, as text. You do not need an image to convey that information.

Answer (score 0):

The `ISBLANK` formula does not work with arrays.  You will need to write it out for each cell.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(AJ17),ISBLANK(AK17),ISBLANK(AL17),ISBLANK(AM17)), "", IF (AD17=0, "", AD17))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements:

- If AJ through AM all contain 0 or are blank then leave AR blank.
- If there are any numbers other than 0 in any cell(s) AJ through AM then whatever is in AD (price or text) shows up in AR.
- If AD is blank AR is blank (not 0)

You were on the right track, but ISBLANK works with individual cells rather than a range reference.  Also, testing for zero is part of the requirement. A blank in AD may show up as a zero in AR.  So your formula needs to be expanded a little.  This solution handles your constraints:

[image]

I've included a few combinations of cell contents to show that it works as intended.  The formula in AR2 is:

```
=IF(VALUE(AJ2&AK2&AL2&AM2&0)=0,"",IF(ISBLANK(AD2),"",AD2))
```

This concatenates the cells from AJ through AM and then tacks on a zero in case all of the cells are blank.  If all of the cells are blank or zero, the value function will produce zero.  In that case, a null is inserted into AR2.  If there is any other number in any of the cells, it tests AD to see if it is blank, in which case, it inserts a null.  Otherwise, it inserts whatever is in AD.